# How to echo total number of entry in a year and month in mysql database in php

Tags: php

The scenario I have here is that, I need to select a Year and Month. And I need to show the Weeks in that currently selected Month. Let me explain it here ... 2017 -> Oct -> Week N ( this should be the Week of year . E.x this week is #40 for 2017.) So I need to list ...

Comment: The explanation is good, but what is your attempt? ... there should be a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provided.

Comment: The php docs contain all the information, and examples, that you need: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
date("W");
```

`W` as a parameter for `date` function will return week number at the current year.

Comment: could you elaborate